# Elasticsearch to find places up to some distance from a set of reference points

Tags: elasticsearch, search, geocoding, geocode

I need help to make a query in order to find which places are less than 1000 meters from some reference points using elasticsearch. I.E.: Which drugstores are less than 1000 meters of an user defined set of subway stations. I have latitude and longitude values of them.

I have found some examples of this type of search on elasticsearch, but all of them are considering a static set of reference points on filters (hard coded lat and lng).

Adding more information:

```
GET /places
{
  "places" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "location" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
}

GET /references
{
"references" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "location" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a search request where I can select documents on places index based on a list of documents on references index. Most example just demonstrate how to search documents like that:

```
GET /places/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "1000m",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The value pin.location/origin in above example is fixed, but I need this based on reference index.

In MySQL should be like that:

```
select pl.latitude, pl.longitude from places as pl
where exists (
select rf.id from references as rf where ST_Distance_Sphere(
        point(pl.longitude, pl.latitude),
        point(rf.longitude, rf.latitude)
    ) < 1000 and rf.name = "subway"
) and pl.name = "drugstore"
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far? We can point you in the right direction but not write everything for you.

Comment: I tried to explain better adding more information.

Comment: Thanks, much better.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK & unfortunately, there is no alternative to `ST_Distance_Sphere` in ES.

Will need to rethink the way you structure your data -- maybe the nearest `n` establishments of each `place`? Say, 5km. Then, if a user requires <= 1km, you can filter out the too-distant ones.

Subway stations/drugstores/etc are mostly fixed locations (both literally & figuratively). They don't change properties/geoloc/etc that often. When they do, simple updates of each nearby place should do the trick.

Comment: Did this approach work @Pierre? How did you ultimately solve this?